# save value after postback at client side using jquery

Tags: jquery

i need to save the value after postback. for ex: i have different tab in the page. when user click on tab i getting the value based on the tab name bind the repeater control. each time when user click on tab same repeater control bind with different. now in the repeater control i have checkbox. so for ex user is in the first tab and check the checkbox and it clicked on second tab. i need to get previous tab checkbox value at client side using jquery or javascript.

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you're saying, but maybe localStorage can help?

```
localStorage.setItem('foo_value', 1)
```

Then when you the user goes back to the old tab...

```
value = localStorage.getItem('foo_value')
// Do something with the value
```

Comment: i need to preserve value after postback at client side using script.what is "localstorage" ? can i write above line in script or somewhere else.

Comment: Yeah, localStorage is javascript, it stores data on the client side.